# Javascript file selector without standard input type=file dialog

Tags: javascript, html

Is there any possibility to provide a file chooser integrated by the website instead showing them in a new window dialog?

Comment: No, it's not...

Answer (score 0):

in the browser? No you can't for security reasons but if you are making a HTML-JS-CSS application alike then you can use cordova or phonegap plugins to make a customizable file chooser

Answer (score 0):

What do you think about a drag & drop?
Maybe this will help
https://www.filestack.com/